# Handling an uninitialized array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

As part of a larger project I decided to work on a C++ c array wrapper, obviously this could instead just be a std vector, but I've learned a lot working on this and it's brought up a few points I'd like to explore further.

After posting my code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113487/c-array-wrapper) I have increaced the complexity of the code. Mostly this has improved the code, but I've also gained some new problems along the way:

Right now the code uses overloaded new to avoid having to default initialize members.

```
Simple_Array(size_type size) :
    _size(size),
    _data(static_cast<pointer>(::operator new(_size * sizeof(value_type))))
{}

template <
    class It,
    class = typename std::enable_if< std::is_constructible< value_type,
        typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type >::value >::type
>
Simple_Array(It first, It last) :
    Simple_Array(std::distance(first, last))
{
    for (iterator i = _data; first != last; ++first, ++i)
        new (i) value_type{*first};
}
```

Because of this the destructor must be called per member:

```
~Simple_Array() {
    for (iterator i = begin(); i != end(); ++i)
        i->~value_type();

    ::operator delete(_data);
}
```

The problem here is best illustrated if you try to create a `Simple_Array<Simple_Array<int>>`, during destruction of such a type, if any member is not initialized then when the uninitialized Simple_Array has it's destructor called it will start playing with uninitialized iterators and cause all kinds of problems. (Note, begin() simply returns _data, and end() returns _data + _size. iterator is a Ty*, _data is a Ty* (c array), and _size is an std::size_t.)

My question is how can I handle this situation of destroying uninitialized members? Am I better off accepting that members require a default constructor?

Comment: this is (one of) the reasons that std::containers use an allocator to handle memory. Suggest you have a look at the source code for std::vector (for example)

Comment: You don't have `capacity`/`size` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 there is a std::size_t _size, however if Simple_Array has 10 uninitialized Simple_Array objects in _data, none of those will have their _size or _data initialized when they are destroyed.

Comment: @RichardHodges I've done a fair amount of reading of stl code, however the Visual C++ stl is pretty awful to read. I picked up some ideas from it such as the SFINAE code came from reading vector and a suggestion in code review.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes I posted an answer that covers the general form that you need to follow. Basically you have to use 2-phase construction: allocate memory then initialise it. No default constructors are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to require objects to be default-constructible.

What you must do is separate the concerns of memory allocation and object initialisation.

This is one of the few legitimate uses of in-place constructors and destructors.

Don't forget to handle the destructor cleanly!!

the constructor should look something like this:

```
SimpleArray(Iter first, Iter last)
: _size(last - first)
, _data(allocate_aligned_uninitialised_memory()) // <- you need to figure this one out
{
   // now we have allocated memory by no copied objects...
   auto dest = &_data[0];
   try {
     while (first != last) {
       // in-place construction
       new (dest)(*first++);
       ++dest;
     }
   }
   catch(...) {
     // if one of the constructors threw, we must unwind the ones that didnt
     while (dest != first) {
       // in-place destruction
       --dest;
       dest->~dest();
     }
     // release the aligned memory
     release_aligned_memory(_data);

     // pass the exception on - we failed to construct
     throw;
   }
}
```

Comment: The only reason why allocators allow allocation of unitialized memory is to provide for `reserve` (and automatic pre-allocation, of course). If the array in question does not have this feature, than no need to support unitialized memory is there.

Comment: Not quite. You also need to be able to manage exceptions during construction - for this you need to separate the concerns of memory allocation and object initialisation.

Comment: @RichardHodges Good thought, that looks like a much safer way to do that, I had considered issues with exceptions thrown during construction, but not how that would interact with overloaded new.

Comment: Nope, you don't. Container does not have to manage exceptions happened during allocation, not at all. It should be transparent to them.

Comment: yes you do (pls check the stl source code). If you don't destruct the objects you have already constructed, they will leak resources and leave unbalanced side-effects. I have fixed the example to reflect the forwarded exception (good catch, thanks)

Comment: STL has a different code - and I told exactly why. Since allocators provide for two-phase initialization (allocate/construct) you need to manage execeptions. And like I said, allocators provide it for reserve and friends. If you use built-in new, with it's built-in guarantees, you do not have to care about exceptions at all.

Comment: Because I am no longer using placement new or overloaded forms of new, I believe destruction should now be handled without such supporting code in the case of a thrown exception. Is that correct? I'll add such a scenario to the test harness for this code and see what results I get.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes, yes, it is correct. By moving away from placement new you completely shielded yourself from any exception handling in your constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA if you don't 2-phase construct, then you will require the user to provide a default constructor. Plus you will get redundant initialisation + assignment in your container's constructor.

Comment: Nope, see my answer above. No two-phases, no need for default constructor.

Comment: @SergeyA now write the second constructor (that takes 2 iterators) without 2-phase construction, involving no redundant initialisation... good luck ;-)

Comment: I did not notice the second question (with iterator version). For this you do need to pre-allocate memory, I do agree.

Comment: @SergeyA well, consolation prize, the test harness shows that you are indeed right about no memory leaks, not that you didn't know that already!

Comment: software is a team effort - we all won today :-)

Comment: Having researched this problem further I decided to go with separating the allocation and initialization using an alloc policy. Hence I've marked this as accepted.